# Deep linking to phpmysql view?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm new to phpMyAdmin 4.6 and I'm frustrated that:

1. It logs me out after a minute or two
2. I seem unable to deep link to a query

For example my URL looks like:

http://mysql.example.com/tbl_select.php?db=staging&table=video_sources&token=eb8f5170f313b1bf0008bf...#tab_Navi_tables

But how does the actual query

```
SELECT * FROM `video_sources` WHERE `video_id` = 123
```

Get encoded in the URL? I want to be able to send a URL to colleague to have a closer look at the records.

Answer (score 0):

1. You might be experiencing [this bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12251), I suggest upgrading your phpMyAdmin (the latest is currently version 4.7.0).
2. This is not really supported as such, for a number of reasons including security and limits on the length of GET requests. You could come close to accomplishing this by sharing a [bookmark of the query](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/bookmarks.html); when creating a bookmark (at the bottom of the SQL window), you can check the box to "Let every user access this bookmark"

[image: Let every user access this bookmark]

You might even go a step further by bookmarking your query and using the same name of the table as the bookmark name, that way the query is automatically run when browsing to that table. Then you can send a link [as explained here](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-access-directly-to-database-or-table-pages), using syntax roughly like `https://example.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?server=1&db=sakila&table=film`